# Can't pass twice pointer with braces

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, pointers

I have a function

```
void myfunction(A**);
```

and a variable

```
A a;
```

I am trying to create an array of one pointer to `a` inline

```
myfunction( {&a} );
```

and fail. It says I am passing `A*`. If I write

```
A *aa[] = {&a};
myfunction( aa );
```

then it works.

Can I create `A**` inline?

Comment: No, the expression `&a` is an r-value, you can't take its address. You can however do `A* pa = &a; myfunction(&pa);`.

Comment: With that said, your `myfunction` seems suspect, why does it need a pointer to a pointer? What is it doing with the pointer? That needs to be known before we can tell you what you should really pass.

Comment: I would suggest you don't be a two star programmer.  If you need an array of pointers, take an array of pointers.  If you need a pointer that you want to modify, take a reference to a pointer.  C++ has a very nice type system that you can leverage.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude why wouldn't it be constant pointer?

Comment: If you actually need to deal with arrays, consider reference to `std::vector` or `std::array` as parameter of `myFunction`.

Answer (score 1):

You can not create as you are saying inline an object of the type A ** because the expression `{&a}` is not an array.

In fact it is the same as to wrote

```
A **p = { &a };
```

Depending on the C++ release the right side expression is considered either as an initializer_list or as an object of the type `A *`.

In any case such an initialization is invalid.

And you need not to create an array though an intermediate variable will be required.

You could write

```
A *p = &a;
myfunction( &p );
```

Maybe you should consider a possibility to redeclare the parameter like `A * &`.

You could do something similar as you are trying to do in a C-program.

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef int A;

void myfunction( A **p )
{
    printf( "**p = %d\n", **p );
}

int main( void ) 
{
    A x = 10;

    myfunction( ( int *[] ){ &x } );
}
```

The program output is

```
**p = 10
```

Comment: Isn't `(int*[]) { &x }` the same as `{ &x }` but converted to type `int*[]` by force?

Comment: @Dims No, it is not the same. I showed in my answer how the initialization of the parameter looks in C++.

Comment: Why isn't it the same?

Comment: @Dims Because C and C++ are two different languages. An interpretation of a braced list is determined by the type of the corresponding parameter The parameter of your function is not an array.

Comment: Is `(int *[] ){ &x }` illegal in C++?

Comment: You might want to emphasize that the program you show is a C program, and not C++ (which doesn't have compound literals).

Comment: @Dims C++ does not support compound literals.

Comment: Even `C++11` doesn't?

Comment: @Dims Even C++ 11 and C++ 20.

Answer (score 1):

> I am trying to create an array of one pointer to a inline
>
> ```
> myfunction( {&a} );
> ```

This does not work, because `&a` is `A*`, which is a different type from `A**`, and those types are not convertible to each other.

> Can I create A** inline?

Yes, if you have a `A*` variable:

```
A* pointer = &a;
myfunction(&pointer);
```

But not from `A a` directly.